# How to, from command line terminal, add system voices and download them in addition to selecting them as the default for MacOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, command-line

How to, from command line terminal, add system voices and download them in addition to selecting them as the default for MacOS Sonoma?  How can I get access without coding to the plist that has the information?